# how to use Serenity/Js for protractor-Jasmine framework tests. Does serentiy support protractor jasmine framework

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, serenity-js

I want to integrate serenity reports for my tests built using protractor-jsamine framework. All the exploration done only shows results for serenity integration with protractor-cucmber framework. Below is my config file sample. What should i add to integrate with Serenity reports. Currently i am using jasmine reporter.

```
   config = {
      framework: 'jasmine2',
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['specs7.js'],
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
      }
    capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'},

     onPrepare: function() {

     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serenity/JS doesn't support Jasmine test runner (yet).
However, it [supports Mocha](http://serenity-js.org/mocha/readme.html), which is a great alternative to Jasmine.

Comment: Serenity/JS version 2 will support Jasmine. Stay tuned! :-)